# Data Annotation Phone Number Conversion

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I want to gracefully **convert phone number** input from my users into a specific phone number format.

- I would like convert this with a **dataAnnotation**, Just as
  `[dataType(dataType.Date)]` displays a `dateTime` as a `string`

Ie:

- 0205938472 into +61205938472
- 02 0593 8472 into +61205938472
- 0593 8472 into +61205938472  (I will assume the area code from where
  they live or if its a mobile)
- 02-0593-8472 into +61205938472

Etc, I also want to convert the other direction:

- +61205938472 into 02 0593 8472 (Or whatever format i choose)

I want to do this to promote readability for the user but retain a strict data type in the database.

**Questions**

1. Is using a dataAnnotation in this manner considered bad practice?
2. How would I actually write the dataAnnotation( /However you would do it)?

   <strike>(please include some code)</strike>  
   Edit: to clarify, i do not want someone to write the extension for me, I would just like an example of key pieces of code and implementation.

**Please Note**

- These are Australia, New Zealand and internationally formatted
  numbers being stored as internationally formatted numbers.
- And International Formatted numbers being converted to Australia, New Zealand or internationally formatted depending on the user's location (which i can determine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the UI you're using, you might be able to do this using a:

- ASP.NET: [Custom binding code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx) (see example)
- ASP.NET MVC: ModelBinder
- WPF: [CustomBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
- Windows Forms: [Custom Converters/Editors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic6)

As parsing and formatting usually happens in the UI layer, I doubt you will find a solution that works at the data/model layer and which will work universally or which can do more than just validation.

In the data annotations namespace, there is a [DataType.PhoneNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx) which you can attach to your properties. Though you, yourself, remain responsible to do the parsing and the formatting using the appropriate display technology.

Answer (score 0):

1. Data annotations and datatype are used for validation, not for converting values. The datatype is mostly used so that the validation knows where to start guessing.

**2. That is asking too much for someone to code an extension like that, especially without showing any effort.**

Comment: I understand, i'll clarify that i am not asking for someone to write the extension for me. I just want some pseudo code on how to implement it, as you said a data annotation is not used for converting values, so how would you do it?

Comment: The validation is only to make sure that the structure is valid (you might want to look into using a `regex data annotation`). It really depends on your implementation and where you " retain a strict data type in the database. " Perhaps this is in a controller, or a manager class, service, factory, repository, etc. Wherever this data interacts with the database is where the conversions or logic need to take place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTypeAttribute like so:

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public string PhoneNumber{get; set;}
```

Comment: Yes, but DataTypes are NOT for Data Validation (even though they derive from a ValidationAttribute). Weird, I know.